# Categorizing dataframe based on information in another dataframe

Tags: r, tidyverse

Im trying to categorize one dataframe based on information in another dataframe. In df1 I have information on the measurement type (e.g. if a jar contained wet or dry soil and whether or not the treatment was "None" or "ul5") at a given time. In df2 I have information on what a measured value X was at a given time. I need to know the measurement type for every measured value of X.

I have tried to use full_join and fill() but neither were able to give me my desired outcome. Any ideas?

Here's df1:

```
df1 <- structure(list(Jar = c("Soil_dry", "Soil_dry", "soil_wet", "soil_wet", 
"Soil_dry", "Soil_dry", "soil_wet"), Treatment = c("None", "None", 
"None", "None", "ul5", "ul5", "ul5"), Timestamp = structure(c(1608129063, 
1608129122, 1608129126, 1608129136, 1608129189, 1608129242, 1608129252
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -7L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(Jar = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Treatment = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Timestamp = structure(list(format = ""), class = c("collector_datetime", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"))
```

df2:

```
df2 <- structure(list(X = c(5, 3, 34, 4, 65, 9, 7), Timestamp = structure(c(1608129064, 
1608129122, 1608129125, 1608129133, 1608129188, 1608129240, 1608129243
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -7L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(X = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), Timestamp = structure(list(format = ""), class = c("collector_datetime", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"))
```

Desired data:

```
desired_data <- structure(list(X = c(5, 3, 34, 4, 65, 9, 7), Timestamp = structure(c(1608129064, 
1608129122, 1608129125, 1608129133, 1608129188, 1608129240, 1608129243
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), Jar = c("Soil_dry", 
"Soil_dry", "Soil_dry", "soil_wet", "soil_wet", "Soil_dry", "Soil_dry"
), Treatment = c("None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "ul5", 
"ul5")), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -7L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(
    X = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", "collector"
    )), Timestamp = structure(list(format = ""), class = c("collector_datetime", 
    "collector")), Jar = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Treatment = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"))
```

Comment: What about a left_join? Like this: `left_join(df2, df1) %>% fill(Jar, Treatment)`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @CainãMaxCouto-Silva, I think it works quite good!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `data.table`'s rolling join.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)
df1[df2, roll = "nearest", on = "Timestamp"]
```

---

If we want to make sure that the row selected is always greater than `Timestamp` from `df2` :

```
library(dplyr)

tidyr::crossing(df1 %>%rename(Timestamp1 = Timestamp), 
                df2 %>% rename(Timestamp2 = Timestamp)) %>%
  mutate(diff = as.numeric(Timestamp2 - Timestamp1)) %>%
  filter(diff > 0) %>% 
  arrange(Jar, Timestamp2, diff) %>%
  group_by(Timestamp2) %>%
  slice(1L) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  arrange(Timestamp2) %>%
  select(-diff)

#  Jar      Treatment Timestamp1              X Timestamp2         
#  <chr>    <chr>     <dttm>              <dbl> <dttm>             
#1 Soil_dry None      2020-12-16 14:31:03     5 2020-12-16 14:31:04
#2 Soil_dry None      2020-12-16 14:31:03     3 2020-12-16 14:32:02
#3 Soil_dry None      2020-12-16 14:32:02    34 2020-12-16 14:32:05
#4 Soil_dry None      2020-12-16 14:32:02     4 2020-12-16 14:32:13
#5 Soil_dry None      2020-12-16 14:32:02    65 2020-12-16 14:33:08
#6 Soil_dry ul5       2020-12-16 14:33:09     9 2020-12-16 14:34:00
#7 Soil_dry ul5       2020-12-16 14:34:02     7 2020-12-16 14:34:03
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @Ronak Shah! I'm wondering if your solution would work in all situations, as I forgot to describe the situation completely in my original question. Let's say there is a value of X at 2020-12-16 14:38:02. I guess this measurement would be categorized as "Soil_wet"/"None", because it is closest to row #10, soil_wet, None, 2020-12-16 14:38:03. Actually it should be soil_dry, because it's only measurements after 14:38:03 that should be categorized as soil_wet.

Comment: Yes, `data.table` rolling join takes the nearest match. For your specific case I think the updated answer should help where we select only those values that occur after the timestamp from `df2`.

Comment: Hm, it looks like the X values are not correct with the updated solution

Comment: I've added some new dummy data that has some better examples e.g. more X-values around 2020-12-16 14:38:00

Comment: What about `X` values? Can you make the example a bit shorter (5 rows maybe) so that it is easier to check. Can you also update your expected output.

Comment: I have edited the example to be shorter and updated the expected outcome.

Comment: Sorry @ Ronak Shah!!! Your code works at it should with the dummy data I presented.

Comment: Using my real dataset I continue to get this Error: cannot allocate vector of size 26.1 Gb @Ronak Shah. However using Cainã Max Couto-Silva's solution works quite fine.

Comment: That solution does a `left_join` so it relies on the fact that there would be an exact match of timestamp somewhere in both the dataframes. If there is no exact match this would return all `NA`'s. Also if you look at the solution closely it will not return correct Timestamp always. For example, if you have an exact match at 2020-12-16 14:38:03 and there is another entry at 2020-12-16 14:38:05 which need to be matched with 2020-12-16 14:38:06 it will take value of 2020-12-16 14:38:03 instead of 2020-12-16 14:38:05.

Comment: Hm, I see. But do you know how to get around the error I get?